# Database design with my SQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

first post, hope I'm doing it right :-)

I'm after running into difficulties with mySQL. I'm trying to create a database and in mySQL workbench I designed the tables and the EER model. I'm just after realising that mySQL workbench is a database design tool used to as a GUI to design the database and that I need mySQL to actually create the database. Is my understanding right? This may seem silly but I am new to MySQL and databases not being 1 of my stronger subjects.

So my question is do I need mySQL server to create an instance of a database and is my understanding right or completely and utterly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a server running to host the database you generate/modify with [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).